# electron-builder Targets: mac vs. mas

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

What is the difference between the 2 `electron-builder` targets for Mac OS X: `mac` vs `mas`? I understand that `mas` is for distribution in the Mac App Store, and `mac` is for distribution outside of it.

1. Is the `mas` package able to auto-update when a new version is published as a Github release? Or must the update be done through the Mac App Store?
2. How do you decide which `mac` targets to use, do they all have a specific use case?

   - pkg
   - dmg
   - zip

Thank you for clearing up my confusion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting Question!!.

1. Is the mas package able to auto-update when a new version is published as a Github release? Or must the update be done through the Mac App Store?

   - No `mas` is not able to auto update coz, it is targeted for the Application Store. We need to manually update it in the app store
2. How do you decide which mac targets to use, do they all have a specific use case?
   **pkg / dmg /zip**

   - DMG is the format where app is installed in OS level i.e it can be accessed through any user. you simple drag and drop the app is the application folder
   - PKG is like a app installer, where there are steps of installation. Main advantage of **PKG** is that it gives us option to install the app at a user level which means app can be install for a specific user only just like window OS. Example in  the picture below.
     [image]

Comment: Great insight! How will you decide whether to distribute your app using pkg, dmg, or both?

Comment: its based on how we are using the machine. 
If the machine we are using is solely for one person like a personal mac, i would recommended **DMG** because it give us a less hassle if there are some update for the App. And
If the machine are being used by multiple people like in case of educational institute or libraries. It better to go with **PKG** for user level installation since the app will have access by that particular user only

Comment: Where does the `.pkg` install the application to? After installing for current user only, I can find the app using Spotlight Search, but cannot find it in the **Applications** folder nor in the current user's home directory

Comment: @AthenaWisdom it should be in `cd ~/Applications`.

Comment: Thank you @raman, can you provide some insight on windows platform as well?
exe vs msi? I am using electron-builder for packaging, finding difficulties in choosing right target. If you can redirect me to the link, which gives pros & cons, it will be great help.